# transform dynamic XML to Adobe InDesign table using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

I'm in trouble with transforming an list of XML-items to a indesign-table. One issue is to calculate the number of rows, because this is needed but can't processed as simple count().

The InDesign-table should look like that:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+
|ARTIKELNR   |BEZEICHNUNG  |VK1BRUTTO   |
+------------+-------------+------------+
|            |TEXT1                     |
+------------+--------------------------+
...
```

The XML looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<kategorie>
  <artikel>
<ARTIKELNR>              200151</ARTIKELNR>
<BEZEICHNUNG>ARTIST ONE - the first release</BEZEICHNUNG>
<TEXT1></TEXT1>
<VK1BRUTTO>13,9900</VK1BRUTTO>
  </artikel>
  <artikel>
<ARTIKELNR>              200153</ARTIKELNR>
<BEZEICHNUNG>ARTIST TWO - the second release</BEZEICHNUNG>
<TEXT1>Lorem ipsum dolor whatever...</TEXT1>
<VK1BRUTTO>13,9900</VK1BRUTTO>
  </artikel>
....
```

As you can see sometimes TEXT1 is empty. In this case: there is no second row for this item.

Therfore I wrote down this (InDesign)XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="ARTIKELNR"/>
<xsl:template name="rowcount">
  <xsl:param name="rows"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="article">
       <xsl:if test="TEXT1 != ''">
          <xsl:call-template name="rowcount">
             <xsl:with-param name="rows" select="$rows + 1" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/kategorie">
<xsl:variable name="rows"><xsl:call-template name="rowcount"/>
/xsl:variable>
<Table aid:tcols="3" aid:trows="$rows" aid:table="table" xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/"> 

    <xsl:for-each select="artikel"> 
        <cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="25.30pt" aid:pstyle="abs_Produkt_Artikelnummer" aid:cstyle="zei_Produkt_Artikelnummer" aid5:cellstyle="zel_Produkt_Artikelnummer" aid:theader=""> 
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(ARTIKELNR, string-length(ARTIKELNR) - 6)"/>
        </cell> 
        <cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="136.76pt" aid:pstyle="abs_Produkt_Bezeichnung" aid:cstyle="zei_Produkt_Bezeichnung" aid5:cellstyle="zel_Produkt_Bezeichnung" aid:theader="">
            <xsl:value-of select="BEZEICHNUNG"/>
        </cell>
        <cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="21.55pt" aid:pstyle="abs_Produkt_VKBrutto" aid:cstyle="zei_Produkt_VKBrutto" aid5:cellstyle="zel_Produkt_VKBrutto" aid:theader="">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(VK1BRUTTO, string-length(VK1BRUTTO), string-length(VK1BRUTTO)-2)"/>
        </cell>
        <xsl:variable name="freitext" select="TEXT1"/>
        <xsl:if test="$freitext != ''">
            <cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:pstyle="abs__empty" aid:cstyle="zei__empty" aid5:cellstyle="zel__empty" aid:theader="">
            </cell>
            <cell aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="2" aid:pstyle="abs_Produkt_Beschreibung" aid:cstyle="zei_Produkt_Beschreibung" aid5:cellstyle="zel_Produkt_Beschreibung" aid:theader="">
                <xsl:value-of select="TEXT1"/>
            </cell>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each> 

</Table>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Failures: 
 1. the number of rows isn't calculated correctly.
 2. InDesign doesn't build a table from it's result.

Can somebody explain what's the problem and maybe give me a correct code?

Comment: Could you post the expected XML result of the transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am guessing correctly, you want to do something like this (non-relevant attributes omitted):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/"
xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/kategorie">
    <Table aid:tcols="3" aid:trows="{count(artikel) + count(artikel/TEXT1[text()])}"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="artikel"> 
            <cell> 
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ARTIKELNR)"/>
            </cell> 
            <cell>
                <xsl:value-of select="BEZEICHNUNG"/>
            </cell>
            <cell>
                <xsl:value-of select="VK1BRUTTO"/>
            </cell>
            <xsl:if test="TEXT1/text()">
                <cell/>
                <cell>
                    <xsl:value-of select="TEXT1"/>
                </cell>
                <cell/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </Table>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Table xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/" aid:tcols="3" aid:trows="3">
   <cell>200151</cell>
   <cell>ARTIST ONE - the first release</cell>
   <cell>13,9900</cell>
   <cell>200153</cell>
   <cell>ARTIST TWO - the second release</cell>
   <cell>13,9900</cell>
   <cell/>
   <cell>Lorem ipsum dolor whatever...</cell>
   <cell/>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. With some more "magic", I did it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/kategorie">
<Produkte>
<Tabelle aid:table="table" aid:tcols="3" aid:trows="{count(artikel) + count(artikel/TEXT1[text()])}" xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/"> 

        <xsl:for-each select="artikel"> 

            <cell aid:table="cell" aid:ccolwidth="25.30" aid:pstyle="abs_Produkt_Artikelnummer" aid:cstyle="zei_Produkt_Artikelnummer" aid5:cellstyle="zel_Produkt_Artikelnummer" > 
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ARTIKELNR)"/>
            </cell> 
            <cell aid:table="cell" aid:ccolwidth="136.76" aid:pstyle="abs_Produkt_Bezeichnung" aid:cstyle="zei_Produkt_Bezeichnung" aid5:cellstyle="zel_Produkt_Bezeichnung">
                <xsl:value-of select="BEZEICHNUNG"/>
            </cell>
            <cell aid:table="cell" aid:ccolwidth="21.55" aid:pstyle="abs_Produkt_VKBrutto" aid:cstyle="zei_Produkt_VKBrutto" aid5:cellstyle="zel_Produkt_VKBrutto">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(VK1BRUTTO, 0, string-length(VK1BRUTTO)-1)"/>
            </cell>
            <xsl:if test="TEXT1/text()">
                <cell aid:table="cell" aid:ccolwidth="25.30" aid:cstyle="zei_Produkt" aid5:cellstyle="zel_Produkt"></cell>
                <cell aid:table="cell" aid:ccolwidth="158.31" aid:ccols="2" aid:pstyle="abs_Produkt_Beschreibung" aid:cstyle="zei_Produkt_Beschreibung" aid5:cellstyle="zel_Produkt_Beschreibung">
                    <xsl:value-of select="TEXT1"/>
                </cell>
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each> 

    </Tabelle>
</Produkte>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hint: to be able to place the table in InDesign, there must be an pseudo-object (i.e. "Produkte") around the table.

Johannes